# Sitecore MVC & Glass Mapper-Bind View Model To View

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I'm just starting with Sitecore MVC & Glass Mapper.

I created a `Heder.cshtml` view & `HeaderViewModel.cs`.

Here's the code of the `HeaderViewModel.cs` file:

```cs
public class HeaderViewModel : IRenderingModel
{
    ISitecoreContext _context = new SitecoreContext();
    public SiteItem siteItem { get; set; }

    public void Initialize(Rendering rendering)
    {
        // Get current item
        var currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        siteItem = Common.GetSiteItem();
        if (siteItem != null)
        {
            // Some code here
        }
    }
 }
```

I'm tring to inherit this `ViewModel` in `Header.cshtml` View as:

```cs
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<FWM.Web.ViewModels.FWM.Composites.HeaderViewModel>
```

But I'm getting error that `Mvc` namespace is not defined in `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web`

How I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glass Mapper has moved its MVC functionality to a separate assembly.
Search for `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc` on NuGet to find the right assembly for your MVC version.

Comment: Thanks I've downloaded the `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5` & it worked.